# Which Stack Exchange is best for a question about project architecture

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need to ask a question about project layout, git repository structure, and IDE settings for the given scenario.  There really won't be a right answer, but rather, an answer which works best for my situation.  What is the best site to ask these types of questions so they don't get closed/locked?

**Being more specific**: I have a grails project that is comprised of several plugins that are basically modules for a grails app.  We're getting ready to make a move from svn to git and I want to make sure I have a good structure going forward. Right now, all the plugins and the app site in one repository.  I want to know if they should be broken up and then I have some additional questions about setting that scenario up in my IDE if that is the way to go, given different git repos for a single project.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: added more to the question. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  That sounds to me like it's broad enough to be useful to other developers migrating from svn to git.  I would think [SO] would be fine, though I'm not sure if a more best-practices angle would be OK on Programmers.  Hopefully others weigh in on this.

Comment: *"There really won't be a right answer"*...that may answer your own question. I don't think questions like that fit anywhere on the network.

Comment: *"There really won't be a right answer"* I think almost all questions fall into this category. The answer you choose is just the best one for your situation. You might try breaking your problem into smaller questions, if possible, but it seems on topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

programmers.stackexchange.com says that it is "not about [...] programming tools (ask on Stack Overflow instead)"

StackOverflow's faq states that it is for "software tools commonly used by programmers".

That should include IDEs and version control specifics, so long as it is a "practical, answerable" problem.